# winforms combobox update both navigation property and id

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, entity-framework-6

My code-first EF6 `Order` entity looks like following:

```
public partial class Order
{
    ...

    public int DispatchMethodID { get; set; }
    public virtual DispatchMethod DispatchMethod { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The corresponding code in the DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<DispatchMethod>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Orders)
        .WithRequired(e => e.DispatchMethod)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.DispatchMethodID)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    ...
}
```

The DispatchMethod class looks like this:

```
public partial class DispatchMethod
{
    public DispatchMethod()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public int DispatchMethodID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Now, I want to bind both my `_Order`'s `DispatchMethod` AND `DispatchMethodID` to the selected value of a combobox:

```
cmbMethod.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _Order, "DispatchMethodID");
```

However, given code only updates the `DispatchMethodID` property, but does not affect `DispatchMethod` navigation property value. What is the best practice and how should I accomplish this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the databinding to DispatchMethod, and not DispatchMethodID? A combobox selected value doesn't have to be an int, it can be an object.

Comment: @Mangist, I need to set **both** my _Order's **DispatchMethod** AND **DispatchMethodID**, not just **DispatchMethod**